# Unity audio bug with scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, scripting

I am building a game on unity on real old version like 5.3. I have a main scene and a menu scene.Each scene got an audio manager script which controls the audio. My problem is with this function called `DontDestroyOnLoad`. More specifically the problem is that when I build the game the game runs perfectly and the menu too but the menu got sounds and the game not.The game has only some sounds that is out of audio manager and I have put them by hand.

My code of audiomanager is here

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Sound
{

    public string name;
    public AudioClip clip;

    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float volume = 0.7f;
    [Range(0.5f, 1.5f)]
    public float pitch = 1f;

    [Range(0f, 0.5f)]
    public float randomVolume = 0.1f;
    [Range(0f, 0.5f)]
    public float randomPitch = 0.1f;

    public bool loop = false;

    private AudioSource source;

    public void SetSource(AudioSource _source)
    {
        source = _source;
        source.clip = clip;
        source.loop = loop;
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        source.volume = volume * (1 + Random.Range(-randomVolume / 2f, randomVolume / 2f));
        source.pitch = pitch * (1 + Random.Range(-randomPitch / 2f, randomPitch / 2f));
        source.Play();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        source.Stop();
    }

}

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static AudioManager instance;

    [SerializeField]
    Sound[] sounds;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            if (instance != this)
            {

                Destroy(this.gameObject);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sounds.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject _go = new GameObject("Sound_" + i + "_" + sounds[i].name);
            _go.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
            sounds[i].SetSource(_go.AddComponent<AudioSource>());
        }

        PlaySound("Music");

    }

    public void PlaySound(string _name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sounds.Length; i++)
        {
            if (sounds[i].name == _name)
            {
                sounds[i].Play();
                return;
            }
        }

        // no sound with _name
        Debug.LogWarning("AudioManager: Sound not found in list, " + _name);
    }

    public void StopSound(string _name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sounds.Length; i++)
        {
            if (sounds[i].name == _name)
            {
                sounds[i].Stop();
                return;
            }
        }

        // no sound with _name
        Debug.LogWarning("AudioManager: Sound not found in list, " + _name);
    }

}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? You have not described it clearly

Comment: Don't use DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
for your manager in the menu scene.

Comment: Sorry for no describe clearly.But i just fixed the bug thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that `DontDestroyOnLoad` will affect the `gameObject` itself, not only the `MonoBehaviour`.

```
void Awake()
{
    if (instance != null)
    {
        if (instance != this)
        {

            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject); // <-- Here
    }
}
```